# Multiple replacements on first line of a very large file

Tags: linux, replace, sed, awk, grep

I have a huge file whose first line is:

> chr    start   end strand  ref_context repeat_masked   s1_smpl_context s1_c_count  s1_ct_count s1_non_ct_count s1_m%   s1_score    s1_snp  s1_indels   s2_smpl_context s2_c_count  s2_ct_count s2_non_ct_count s2_m%   s2_score    s2_snp  s2_indels   s3_smpl_context s3_c_count  s3_ct_count s3_non_ct_count s3_m%   s3_score    s3_snp  s3_indels...

Up to s8.

I want to replace all instances of `s1` to `s4` with `L1` to `L4` and then all instances of `s5` to `s8` with `W1` to `W4`.
Is it best to do this with `grep` or `awk` or some other way?

Comment: Exactly how big is the file?

Comment: The file has 30 million lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `s[1-4]` with `L[1-4]` and  `s[5-8]` with `W[1-4]` only on the first line in the file:

```
sed -Ee '1s/s([1-4])/L\1/g' -e '1s/s([5-8])/W\1/g' -e '1y/5678/1234/' -e '1q' file
```

Demo:

> $ cat file
>
> chr start end strand ref_context repeat_masked s1_smpl_context s1_c_count s1_ct_count s1_non_ct_count s1_m% s1_score s1_snp s1_indels s2_smpl_context s2_c_count s2_ct_count s2_non_ct_count s2_m% s2_score s2_snp s2_indels s3_smpl_context s3_c_count s3_ct_count s3_non_ct_count s3_m% s3_score s3_snp s3_indels s4_Smpl_context s4_c_count s4_ct_count s4_non_ct_count s4_m% s4_score s4_snp s4_indels s5_smpl_context s5_c_count s5_ct_count s5_non_ct_count s5_m% s5_score s5_snp s5_indels s6_smpl_context s6_c_count s6_ct_count s6_non_ct_count s6_m% s6_score s6_snp s6_indels s7_Smpl_context s7_c_count s7_ct_count s7_non_ct_count s7_m% s7_score s7_snp s7_indels s8_smpl_context s8_c_count s8_ct_count s8_non_ct_count s8_m% s8_score s8_snp s8_indels
>
> s1_line_2
>
> s3_line_3
>
> s8_line_4
>
> $ sed -Ee '1s/s([1-4])/L\1/g' -e '1s/s([5-8])/W\1/g' -e '1y/5678/1234/' -e '1q' file
>
> chr start end strand ref_context repeat_masked L1_smpl_context L1_c_count L1_ct_count L1_non_ct_count L1_m% L1_score L1_snp L1_indels L2_smpl_context L2_c_count L2_ct_count L2_non_ct_count L2_m% L2_score L2_snp L2_indels L3_smpl_context L3_c_count L3_ct_count L3_non_ct_count L3_m% L3_score L3_snp L3_indels L4_Smpl_context L4_c_count L4_ct_count L4_non_ct_count L4_m% L4_score L4_snp L4_indels W1_smpl_context W1_c_count W1_ct_count W1_non_ct_count W1_m% W1_score W1_snp W1_indels W2_smpl_context W2_c_count W2_ct_count W2_non_ct_count W2_m% W2_score W2_snp W2_indels W3_Smpl_context W3_c_count W3_ct_count W3_non_ct_count W3_m% W3_score W3_snp W3_indels W4_smpl_context W4_c_count W4_ct_count W4_non_ct_count W4_m% W4_score W4_snp W4_indels

Comment: consider also using the `-i` argument to do the replacement inline so that the huge file isn't replicated into temporary space.

Comment: @nullrevolution.  Using `-i` makes of copy of the file using a temporary file.  It is merely syntactic sugar to prevent the user from having to do the redirection themselves, and serves to obfuscate what is happening, tricking people into believing that no temporary file is used.  It should be avoided.

Comment: Also consider adding `-e '2q'` to quit sed at the second line. The above will read through the whole file (and the file is huge) even when it has to do no edits anymore.

Comment: @sudo_O `sed -Ee '1s/s([1-4])/L\1/g' -e '1s/s([5-8])/W\1/g' -e '1y/5678/1234/' -e '1q' file` 
returns -E as an invalid option

Comment: It's probably minus `-r` then, do `--help` and look for the `extended regexp` option.

Comment: @sudo_O If I have a whole group of similar .gz files `file1 file2 file3` what would be the best way to produce a shell script to cycle through these files and replace the header as above?

Answer (score 0):

As none of your replacements changes the length of the first line, you also have the option to modify the original file directly. I don't think you can do this with any of the usual shell commands, but you could write a program in e.g. Python to do this.

However, I only would consider this option if the file is so huge that you cannot afford to make a temporary copy of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

# On windows, you need to use os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY
fd = os.open('modex', os.O_RDWR)
f = os.fdopen(fd)
f.seek(0)
line = f.readline()
replacements = [("s%s" % x, "L%s" % x) for x in range(1,5)] \
        + [("s%s" % (x+4), "W%s" % x) for x in range(1,5)]
for (s,r) in replacements:
    line = line.replace(s, r)
# We cannot use python file objects here, because f.write() _always_ appends,
# regardless of the seek position. So we use the raw object here.
# Mixing raw IO and python IO should be done with care, however we should be
# ok here, as we did not write anything yet.
os.lseek(fd, 0, os.SEEK_SET)
os.write(fd, line)
f.close()
```